# Can kube-apiserver allow the unsecure connection outside of localhost?

Tags: coreos, kubernetes, etcd

I'm trying to setup a kubernetes cluster for a development environment (local vms).  Because it's development I'm not using working certs for the api-server. It would seem I have to use the secure connection in order to connect minion daemons such as `kube-proxy` and `kubelet` to the master's `kube-apiserver`.  Has anyone found a way around that? I haven't seen anything in the docs about being able to force the unsecure connection or ignoring that the certs are bad, I would assume there's a flag for it when running either the minion or master daemons, but I've had no luck. Etcd is working, it shows any entry from both master and minions and the logs show attempts at handshakes but definitely failing due to bad certs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the flag `--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0` when starting kube-apiserver to allow access to the unauthenticated api endpoint running on port 8080 to your network (by default it is only accessible on localhost).